# How to run macro from another spreadsheet and wait for execution?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet (let's name it Spr1) that I need to refresh periodically. I don't want to refresh it every time I open it, because it takes time.

I created another "launcher spreadsheet" (Spr2) to start Spr1 with macro in argument.

Spr2 is opening with:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.Visible = True
Application.Run "'\\path\Spr1.xlsm'!Refresh_data"
Workbooks("Spr1.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True
Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Macro in Spr1:

```vb
Sub Refresh_data()
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```

The first macro is not waiting for second one to finish the refresh. It is terminating Excel right after opening Spr1.

How can I wait to finish "Refresh_data"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on type of default you have set.

Find your **Query Properties**, and set '**Enable background refresh**' to **False** (Microsoft use True as default).

Then in your code you need to call for RefreshAll and wait for the data to load with the DoEvents. If you want your update of data to run on open you can use this in 'ThisWorkbook' Object.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
For Each q In ThisWorkbook.Connections
q.Refresh
DoEvents
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: But this code, placed in **Spr1** will refresh spreadsheet automatically on opening right? That's what I want to avoid.

Comment: Then don`t use it in Workbook_Open() but the in your Refresh_data() sub

Comment: How should I Dim q as? As queries?

Comment: Tried it like this:
`Sub Refresh_data()
    Dim q As Queries
    For Each q In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    q.Refresh
    DoEvents
    Next
End Sub`
Not working, Type mismatch error

Comment: Try Dim q As Object then - It is just a reference to the object, so I don`t need to dim it. Try to put MsgBox q.Name in the loop.

Comment: Sorry but it's not working. OK, it's refreshing data but it's still interrupted with first macro which is executing line `Workbooks("Spr1.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True` before refresh  finish the job.

Comment: Have you removed the background refresh then as first described? - If Enable background refresh' is False it force the DoEvent to wait until the query is finished. Otherwise (as defaut allow background refresch) code will interrupt your update before your Save.

Comment: Removing this checkbox did the trick. However this script has to be slightly modified as well. This is correct:

`Sub refresh_data()
Dim q As Object
For Each q In ThisWorkbook.Connections
q.Refresh
DoEvents
Next q
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

If you like to launch your update from a VBScript you can call your macro without even se Excel doing the work in the background. Use Notepad and past this code in and save as **MyStarter.vbs** where you can start it with a double click.

```
Dim xlApp
Dim xlWkb
Dim MyParam 
MyParam = InputBox("Input your Parameter:","Enter parameter to the service")
if MyParam <> false then
Set xlApp = CreateObject("excel.application")
Set xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\\path\Spr1.xlsm",true,true)
xlApp.Run "Spr1.xlsm!Refresh_data", CStr(MyParam)
Set xlWkb = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
end if
```

Then you can use your input parameter sent to the instance of your workbook like this :

```
Sub Refresh_data(MsgFromVBScript As String)
MsgBox ("This is your parameter from VBScript:" & MsgFromVBScript)
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub
```